# Authentication issue while using Ajax in Liferay

Tags: liferay

I am using Liferay 5.2.3.I have integrated SweetDev Ria with it to use some Ajax components.The issue I am facing is, the prompt for authentication (Liferay username & password) whenever I land up in a page using this ajax component. Is there any way out of this?

Answer (score 0):

How does your server side component look like? If you have a servlet, you're outside of the portal environment. If you use a portlet, make sure to use the resource-action for handling the Ajax request: There you have full access to the portal world, i.e. logged in user etc.

Also, you might want to update to a more recent version of Liferay to stay current.

Comment: Yes, I got it, the servlet which was rendering the  resource was outside the portal environment which caused the prompts for authentication.